# Cakephp url customisation for SEO

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo, cakephp-1.3, url-routing

I am developing a medical products search site. I need to display my site in search engines whenever a user try to search [COMPANY NAME] medicine [DISEASE]. For this, i created a page in my site which reads COMPANY NAME and DISEASE from url and lists all products.

Now i need to give this page a url like www.sitename.com/[COMPANY NAME]_medicine_[DISEASE].html
I am using Cakephp framework for development. Is there anyway to implement this url formatting in routes.php ? Or is there any other way ? please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about separating them with slashes?

```
// www.sitename.com/[COMPANY NAME]/medicine/[DISEASE]

Router::connect('/:company/medicine/:disease', array('controller' => 'diseases', 'action' => 'index'),
                                               array('pass'=>array('company','disease'),
                                               'company'=>"[a-zA-Z\.]+*",
                                               'disease'=>'[a-zA-Z\.]+'));
```

and the controller

```
function diseases($company,$disease){

}
```

I'm not sure if you can use the underscore instead of the slashes, I have never tried it before. if you do try I'd like to know the results =)

Good Luck

**EDITED**: ok, i was too curious about this issue and i wrote a route like this

```
Router::connect('/:company_medicine_:disease', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'test'),
                                               array('pass'=>array('company','disease'),
                                               'company'=>'[a-zA-Z]+',
                                               'disease'=>'[a-zA-Z]+'));
```

and its not working u_U

as i suspected, the problem is that Cake thinks that the name of the [custom route element](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration#Defining-Routes-948) is `:company_medicine` and not `:company`.. after a few minutes regarding/reading the code of Cake i found out the exact place where Cake parses the route and extracts the names of the passed elements. It's in **/cake/libs/router.php** in the class **CakeRoute**, method **_writeRoute()** (about line 1369):

```
preg_match_all('#:([A-Za-z0-9_-]+[A-Z0-9a-z])#', $parsed, $namedElements);
```

so as you can see in the regexp, the names of the elements can contain an underscore,therefore Cake thinks the name of the parameter is ":company_medicine".
So you have four solutions:

- use slashes as separators for your urls
- change the order of your parameter so it would be `medicine_[COMPANY]_[DISEASE]`
- modify the line 1369 of the **router.php** to this (NOT RECOMENDED, i think it will break routes for plugins):

  `preg_match_all('#:([A-Za-z0-9]+)#', $parsed, $namedElements);`
- use url rewrite in your .htaccess to redirect all `[COMPANY]_medicine_[DISEASE]` to `[COMPANY]/medicine/[DISEASE]` so cake will see it separated by slashes and the browser will see it separated bu underscores. (I haven't tested it, i've never added another rule to the .htaccess for Cake =P)